# How to encrypt the tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to encrypt a particular table in phpmyadmin. If i click on the table it should ask for the password. Please help me out in solving this problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, try to provide as much detail as possible as: research, what did you try... Just exposing a problem it is not showing your effort in order to fix it.

Comment: To be honest I have not wriiten any sql, well I am looking for, is it possible to encrypt the database(tables) in phpmyadmin. I have googled a lot to search solution for this problem, well i have found results for encrypting the columns in database not the entire database. Thanks